# Python: average outdegree in directed network. Why stuck?

Tags: python, numpy, networkx

This is my first StackOverflow post; I am a beginning python user. I have a directed network built into several layers of dictionaries (indexed by town, by sex, etc.). I am trying to calculate mean and SD of outdegree for the egos only, separated by sex and town. This seems like it should be straightforward but I find myself quite stuck--I think the problem lies in the object type as list/array, but I can't figure it out. Your help would be greatly appreciated. If more details are needed, please let me know. Many thanks!

Here is the problematic section of code (the edge list was read in and dictionaries of networks were built without a problem):

```
def town_stats(Dictionary_of_Networks, all_town_nos, all_wave_groups, all_sex_types):

    for vn in all_town_nos:

        for vw in all_wave_groups:

            for vs in all_sex_types:

                if vw=="EGOS":

                    out_values = D[vn][vw][vs].out_degree().values() 
                    #only want to calculate outdegree for EGOS 
                    out_degree=np.array(out_values)
                    avgoutdegree=out_degree/(D[vn][vw][vs].number_of_nodes()) 
                    #I'd like a single number for the mean outdegree for each town for  
                    #males, and another mean for each town for females.
                    avg_outdegreelist=list(avgoutdegree) 
                    #how to fix-> don't want list just a single number for each town. 
                    sd_outdegree = np.std(out_degree)

                print "  Network number %d type %s: %d nodes and %d edges. Average   
                outdegree: %r" % (vn, vs, D[vn][vw][vs].number_of_nodes(), D[vn][vw] 
                [vs].number_of_edges(), avg_outdegreelist) 
                print ""
```

Comment: The code you have posted can't be run by others without calculating the inputs (which are complex in this case), so it's hard to debug. Please consider submitting a *minimal* example in future that reproduces your problem.

Comment: That aside, you might find the `numpy.array` methods useful; you can calculate the mean with `out_degree.mean()` and standard deviation with `out_degree.std()` and so on.

Comment: As a general comment, there are lots of Python packages that are specifically designed for dealing with graphs, e.g. [`graph_tool`](http://graph-tool.skewed.de/) [`igraph`](http://igraph.org/redirect.html), [`networkx`](https://networkx.github.io/)... These libraries have efficient methods for computing network summary statistics, which would probably save you a lot of time and effort in the long run.